# vue.js cannot call function inside a function in created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, typeerror, sweetalert

I'm trying to code a response to websocket messages in vue.js using sweetalert.

Sadly I cannot call sweetalert or a function I defined in methods inside the onmessage in created.

Uncaught TypeError: this.confirmation is not a function
at WebSocket.connection.onmessage

```
  methods: {
    confirmation(response) {
      if (response.data == "stop") {
        this.$swal({
          icon: "success",
          text: "stopped!",
        });
      }
      if (response.data == "start") {
        this.$swal({
          icon: "success",
          text: "started!",
        });
      }
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.connection.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log(event.data);
      this.confirmation(event);
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
created() {
    const that = this;
    this.connection.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log(event.data);
      that.confirmation(event);
    };
}
```

Functions that are defined with the `function` keyword have their own `this`. Using the `that` variable preserves the outer scope's `this` so the inner scope can access it.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it

Comment: You've identified the root cause. This is a good example to explain what OP did wrong. After learning about the context of this, OP should consider using Arrow Functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with the usage of `this`, as it seems like your method is called in the wrong context. [Details on the usage of this in js here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).
I'd problably just define the function elsewhere, where you can access it without using `this`. There might be an more elegant way, but I'm honestly not to familiar with the indepths of javascript

Answer (score 0):

While @Neferin 's answer is generally correct, you can use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to handle cases like this. Functions defined with a `function` keyword has its own scope meaning that it has its own `this`. Arrow-functions do not have a scope.

Here is an example:

```
 created() {
    this.connection.onmessage = (event) => {
      //                               ^^^^
      // in an arrow function, `this` is from parent scope
      console.log(event.data);
      this.confirmation(event);
    };
  },
```

Comment: Oh, than was ancient question :3